# Why C++ can't see my lua script file?

Tags: c++, lua

I have a simple problem with integrating Lua with c++. 
I have my project in Visual Studio : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNw6H.png

and I run my lua_init() function :

```
bool lua_init(std::string &luaScriptName){
// Create the Lua state. Explanation from Lua 5.1 Ref. Manual:

globalL = luaL_newstate(); // 5.1 OK - Lua 5.0 or lower will probably require different commands

if( globalL == NULL )
    return false;

    // Loads all Lua standard libraries
luaL_openlibs(globalL);  // 5.1 OK - Lua 5.0 or lower will require different commands

// This lot below could be replaced with luaL_dofile, but that just does: luaL_loadfile(..) || lua_pcall(..), which gives no reporting of error messages etc.
int initError = luaL_loadfile(globalL,luaScriptName.c_str());
switch( initError )
{
    case 0:
        // The file loaded okay, so call it as a protected function - to stop fatal errors from exiting the program
        lua_pcall(globalL,0,0,0);
        break;
    case LUA_ERRFILE:
        std::cerr<<"Cannot find / open lua script file: "<<luaScriptName<<std::endl<<"Skipping Lua init."<<std::endl;
        break;
    case LUA_ERRSYNTAX:
        std::cerr<<"Syntax error during pre-compilation of script file: " <<luaScriptName<<std::endl<<"Skipping Lua init."<<std::endl;
        break;
    case LUA_ERRMEM:
        // Treating this as fatal, since it means other Lua calls are unlikely to work either
        std::cerr<<"Fatal memory allocation error during processing of script file: " <<luaScriptName<<std::endl;
        return false;
}
return true;
```

}

but don't know I get the "Cannot find / open lua script file:" error

should I point somehow my script.lua to the Visual Studio ? the file is located in the project directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will exectue where the binary is, or in the target directory in Debugging Mode. So check that your lua file is accessible to your binary when you execute it. If it's with your source files, sure, it's not accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have changed the Visual Studio's Working Directory and I did put in there my script.lua. I don't get the error about not finding the file but the script is not executed anyway - I don't see the HelloWorld in the console.

Comment: So 1. my answer was correct, then check it! 2. I don't know what your script is supposed to do! 3. if your script is supposed to print hello world, check that the output of your lua vm is the console. I really doubt your vm output to your standard output but you'll have to check yourself. Anyway, if you don't have any error, then the script is loaded (is it run? I don't remember if it's enough to just load it) so look in lua code.

Comment: Ok, so firstly my script is just : `print("hello world");` secondly: I have made a new project in VS (not with ogreAppWizard but normal c++ project) and copied the same files into it and now everything runs just fine. I think the problem is more ogre specific - as you said something about lua vm - how can I check it ?

Comment: Check the lua doc. If I remember correctly, there are ways to wire the print() function to some specific output, but by default it will output to the C standard output that might be deactivated in your case or something like that. Just check where it goes currently, rewire it to your output device and you'll make it run. Did you forget to "check" my answer? :)

Comment: I will try to take a look in the lua doc ( but as I have looked recently it was quite complicated for me :( ). I have found this piece of code to run console in ogre: [link](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1996) and I have put it into my code but besides many different things I cannot see the lua script's "Hello World"

btw. sry I cannot 'check' your answer cuz I have too few reputation points :(